# Redirect myWebSite:8086.com to new domain

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, url-rewriting

I have two websites on a server:

1. myWebSite:80.com
2. myWebSite:8086.com

We are moving myWebSite domain and the site on port 80 to Azure App service (website1.azurewebsites.net). Also, the site on port 8086 to another Azure App service (website2.azurewebsites.net).

The problem is that mobile app is using myWebSite:8086.com in code. As myWebSite domain will be assigned to website1.azurewebsites.net, how do I redirect   myWebSite:8086.com calls to website2.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: Are you changing the DNS of the domain to point to your Azure site's IP? If so then surely it's not a problem?

Comment: @ADyson, I believe that the issue is that what was a single domain with different ports is now going to two different Web Apps.

Comment: we are updating the A record to point myWebSite domain to website1.azurewebsites.net (IP of website1.azurewebsites.net)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Web Apps can only answer requests on ports 80 and 443. You won't be able to use an Azure Web App for port 8086.

A possible alternative is to spin up a VM and host both web apps that way. Then you can answer on any port that you choose.

Comment: website1.azurewebsites.net is on port 80. The traffic for myWebSite:8086.com which is port 8086 will hit website1.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: @user1663715, I believe I've misstated things. You are deploying an App Service Environment, and not Azure Web Apps, correct? Because Web Apps in an App Service Plan can only receive traffic via ports 80 and 443.

Comment: I am using Azure Web Apps